# Error in SonarQube Scanner Execution [Windows - Linux Master-Slave]

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarscanner

I have SonarQube Server and Jenkins instance running on Windows machine.

I have created Jenkins job to generate Code Coverage Report with SonarQube.
This job runs on Linux machine

1. Build Code
2. Run Unit Test-Cases
3. Run Sonar Scanner

But later I get error in jenkins

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute SonarQube
ERROR: Caused by: Fail to get bootstrap index from server
ERROR: Caused by: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9000
```

The error is right as my server is running on Windows machine and not on linux (127.0.0.1).

**Want to know that how to resolve this?** and get result on Windows. Is it possible ?

Comment: you are expecting we guess what are you doing from a error message ? please also note that cygwin-1.7.4-1 is 8 years old. https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin-announce/2010-04/msg00005.html may be time to make something more recent ?

Comment: Does your code compile without errors and *warnings* without those flags? And does it execute successfully? If not, fix that first, including warning!

Comment: Yes. Code compiles successfully after removing those flags

Comment: Have you made sure SonarQube is up before running the job from Jenkins ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the sonar server name / details needs to be checked. not sure if you are using the plugin or sonar runner for execution. either ways validate the sonar.host.url value and ensure it mapped to the correct hostname and port.